# Datatables not displaying first column

Tags: jquery, json, database, datatables

I have an JSON object that I am trying to display in table using jquery datatables but the first column is not showing. I know that the data is in the JSON object but that data is not displaying.
Can anyone see what is the problem with my code please?
Thanks!

```
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.15/datatables.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/bs-3.3.5/jqc-1.11.3,dt-1.10.8/datatables.min.js"></script>  
<meta charset="utf-8">
<a href="index.html">
<img border="0"  src="home.png" width="50" height="50">

</a>
<style>
.pull-right{float:right!important;}
.pull-left{float:left!important;}
</style>

<script>
    /* set up XMLHttpRequest */
    function asyncReq(callback){
    var url = "LICENCIAMENTOS_PROJECTOS.xlsx";
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.open("GET", url, true);
    oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";

    oReq.onload = function(e) {
        var arraybuffer = oReq.response;

        /* convert data to binary string */
        var data = new Uint8Array(arraybuffer);
        var arr = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i != data.length; ++i) arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
        var bstr = arr.join("");

        /* Call XLSX */
        var workbook = XLSX.read(bstr, {
           type: "binary"
        });

        /* DO SOMETHING WITH workbook HERE */

        var sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[2];

        /* Get worksheet */


        var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[sheet_name];
        var oficios = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet,{range:2});

        callback(oficios);
        }
        oReq.send();
    }

    asyncReq(function(result){
    console.log(result);
    //DataTable     
        $('#tabela-oficios').DataTable( {
                "dom": '<"pull-left"f><"pull-right"l>tip',
                "aaData": result,
                "aoColumns": [
                    { "mData": "Conc.",
                        sDefaultContent: ''},
                    { "mData": "Nº PT",
                        sDefaultContent: ''},
                    { "mData": "Procº ",
                        sDefaultContent: ''},
                    { "mData": "Designação",
                    sDefaultContent: ''},
                    { "mData": "Clausulas (S/N)",
                        sDefaultContent: ''},
                    { "mData": "Nº Oficio",
                        sDefaultContent: ''},   
                    { "mData": "SGD",
                        sDefaultContent: ''},   
                    { "mData": "Data Oficio",
                        sDefaultContent: ''},   
                    { "mData": "Data Resposta",
                        sDefaultContent: ''},   
                    { "mData": "Informação para resolução clausulas",
                        sDefaultContent: ''},   
                    { "mData": "Data inf da AO resolução clausulas",
                        sDefaultContent: ''}]                       
            });             


        }); 

</script>
```

```
            <h1 align="center">LICENCIAMENTOS</h3> 
            <h3 align="center">Registo de Oficios que Carecem de Resposta</h3> 
            <table id="tabela-oficios" class="display compact" style="text-align:center; margin: 0 auto;" > 
                 <thead>  
                      <tr>  
                           <th>Conc.</th>  
                           <th>Nº PT</th>  
                           <th>Número do Processo</th>
                           <th>Designação</th>
                           <th>Clausulas (S/N)</th> 
                           <th>Nº Oficio</th>  
                           <th>SGD</th>  
                           <th>Data Oficio</th>
                           <th>Data Resposta</th>
                           <th>Informação para resolução clausulas</th>  
                           <th>Data inf da AO resolução clausulas</th>  
                        </tr>  
                 </thead>  
            </table>
```

Here is an image to show you what is happening:
[image]

Comment: Every thing looks fine. just to debug 

1. try moving first column to 2nd place 
{ "mData": "Conc.",
    sDefaultContent: ''},
    
2. change Conc. to Número do Processo see if it works 

{ "mData": "Conc.",
    sDefaultContent: ''},

Comment: Maybe it's the dot in `Conc.` that's causing the problem - try using `"mData": 0,` for the first column

Comment: @markpsmith I also felt so but there are other fields also having special character and works fine

Comment: I don't see any other column named with a dot, full-stop, period, w/e. Did you try `"mData": 0,`? Just try it - rule it out.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! I solved the problem by changin the name. I think @markpsmith was right and the problem was the dot, somethin that i think its strange. But anyway its working now! Thanks :)

Comment: Hello! i hope you read thi guys. As i load my page it takes sometime for the table to show, like 4 seconds. While i wait for the table the headers that i defined in the body show but the table is not there.
It's just an aesthetic problem but i would like to hide the headers until the table is loaded. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your css with DOM Explorer since css might have override the behavior.
In my case following css has caused the issue.

```
a {
color:white;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: transparent;
}
```